# Maximum Diffraction of Waves Through a Single Slit

Tags: waves, diffraction

So I've been trying to find an answer to this question and keep getting two different responses:

a) Maximum diffraction occurs when the wavelength of the wave is equal (or similar) to the opening of the slit

b) Maximum diffraction occurs when the size of the slit opening is smaller than the wavelength of the wave?

Which is the correct answer? Or are both these answers applicable depending on the type of wave examined (i.e. sound vs. light)

Thanks!!

Comment: Try it out: https://phet.colorado.edu/sims/html/wave-interference/latest/wave-interference_en.html

Comment: If you know how the diffraction caused by a slit depends on the experimental parameters you'll be able to answer your own question.

Comment: @flippiefanus, The thing is, I don't know how it depends on these parameters

Comment: Then that should be your question. Perhaps you can edit it so that a suitable answer can be provided. However, there's a lot of information about that available on the internet. For instance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction